# Problema con el linker en un proyecto de múltiples archivos en C++

Tags: c++, headers

tengo un problema con un proyecto que empecé a programar hace un tiempo con practicas que no eran las mejores (implementaciones de funciones en archivos de cabecera y tal) y mientras estaba aprendiendo más sobre C++ decidí que reharía todo el proyecto aplicando las buenas prácticas, es así como empecé a separar las definiciones de las declaraciones en archivos diferentes .h y .cpp, usando "header guards" y poniendo en los headers solo declaraciones de funciones, definiciones de clases y estructuras y las variables globales indispensables. Pero entonces viene el linker a soltar como 243 errores de definiciones múltiples, lo mismo de variables globales como de funciones. Estoy trabajando en Dev-C++ con mingw32 y la librería Allegro 4, pero supongo que no haya que conocerla para responder mi problema.

Me parece que no hay otra forma de explicar bien este problema que pasando el código, aunque no es todo el proyecto, sino solo una pequeña muestra lo más reducida posible en la que pude reproducir el error, que si me lo aclaran supongo que pueda solucionarlo en todo el resto del proyecto.

El proyecto de muestra tiene 4 archivos: main.cpp, global.h, framework.h, global.cpp, global.h

main.cpp

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include "..\headers\framework.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(iniciar_framework(argv[1], argc) != 0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    ejecutar_framework();
    
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

global.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include <allegro.h>
#include <string>

const int FRAME_RATE = 30;

volatile unsigned int counter; //En Allegro, para que cumpla su funcion, es obligatorio que esta variable sea global y volatile

void aumentar_counter();

BITMAP *buffer;

#endif
```

framework.h

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORK_H
#define FRAMEWORK_H

void instalar_allegro();

void inicializar();

void deinicializar();

void ciclo_logico();

void ciclo_grafico();

int iniciar_framework(char* file, int argc);

void ejecutar_framework();

#endif
```

global.cpp

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_CPP
#define GLOBAL_CPP

#include <string>

#include "..\headers\global.h"

void aumentar_counter(){
    counter++;
}
END_OF_FUNCTION(aumentar_counter)

#endif
```

framework.cpp

(Disculpen si está un poco largo, aunque traté de reducirlo lo más posible)

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORK_CPP
#define FRAMEWORK_CPP

#include <allegro.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "..\headers\framework.h"
#include "..\headers\global.h"

using namespace std;

void instalar_allegro(){
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    install_timer();
    
    set_uformat(U_ASCII);
    
    LOCK_VARIABLE(counter);
    LOCK_FUNCTION(aumentar_counter);
    
    install_int_ex(aumentar_counter, BPS_TO_TIMER(FRAME_RATE));
    
    srand(time(NULL));
}

void inicializar(){
    set_color_depth(32);
    
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640,480 ,0,0);
    
    buffer = create_bitmap(SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);
    
    clear_to_color(buffer, 0x008040);
}

void deinicializar(){
    destroy_bitmap(buffer);
}

void ciclo_logico(){
}

void ciclo_grafico(){
    blit(buffer, screen, 0,0 , 0,0 , SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);
}

int iniciar_framework(char* file, int argc){
    instalar_allegro();
    
    inicializar();
    
    return 0;
}

void ejecutar_framework(){
    while(!key[KEY_ESC]){
        if(counter){
            while(counter){
                ciclo_logico();
                counter--;
            }
            
            ciclo_grafico();
        }else{
            rest(1);
        }
    }
    
    deinicializar();
}

#endif
```

Y finalmente, me parece absurdo no incluir los errores que da el linker cuando compilo el programa

```
D:\Programación\C++\Allegro\Map loader new\sources\global.o global.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `counter'
D:\Programación\C++\Allegro\Map loader new\sources\framework.o  framework.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
D:\Programación\C++\Allegro\Map loader new\sources\global.o global.cpp:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `buffer'
D:\Programación\C++\Allegro\Map loader new\sources\framework.o  framework.cpp:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
D:\Programación\C++\Allegro\Map loader new\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Este es, muy resumido, el código que contiene mi error. Les agradecería que me explicaran dónde está y cuáles son las mejores prácticas que debería utilizar para evitarlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si no explicas tu situación es imposible ayudarte. Puedes empezar por enumerar los errores que obtienes.

Comment: Vale, es que solo esperaba que me dijeran todo lo que tengo que hacer para quedar bien con el linker a ver si me faltó algo, pero te entiendo. De todas formas, como son errores de linker que implican múltiples definiciones de variables, me parece que lo mejor seria pasar el código (aunque está un poco largo, traté de reducirlo lo más posible) y que ustedes me digan. Voy y edito.

Comment: @Mateo El tiene el mismo problema que te mencione la otra vez, defina una variable global en un archivo .h sin declararla inline

Answer (score 3):

Una de las razones por la cual el modificador `inline` no este funcionando es porque tu compilador no esta configurado con el estándar c++17, que cambio el modificador `inline` para las variables globales, léase mas [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work), entonces tienes que usar el método antiguo de usar el modificador `extern`:

### global.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include <allegro.h>
#include <string>

// declaramos las variables globales
extern const int FRAME_RATE;
extern volatile unsigned int counter; //En Allegro, para que cumpla su funcion, es obligatorio que esta variable sea global y volatile
extern BITMAP *buffer;

void aumentar_counter();

#endif
```

### global.cpp

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_CPP
#define GLOBAL_CPP

#include <string>

#include "..\headers\global.h"

// definimos las variables globales
const int FRAME_RATE = 30;
unsigned int counter = 0; //En Allegro, para que cumpla su funcion, es obligatorio que esta variable sea global y volatile
BITMAP *buffer = NULL;

void aumentar_counter(){
    counter++;
}
END_OF_FUNCTION(aumentar_counter)

#endif
```

Nota: el modificador `extern` básicamente lo que hace es que puedes declarar varias veces la variable pero tienes que definirla solo una ves en un .cpp, puedes leer mas [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: Al final, eso mismo fue lo que hice, declarar todo como extern, y además cambié el orden de los #includes teniendo en cuenta cómo quedaría cuando el preprocesador hiciera su trabajo. Y fue lo que me resultó. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problemas es que define una variable global en un archivo encabezado que se incluyen en más de un archivo de código fuente de tu programa y al final el compilador al unir todos los archivos de código fuente para crear el ejecutable encontrará más de una definición de esa variable, al ser una variable global solo se puede definir una vez, al menos que la declares [inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) y el linker sabrá que esa variable también estará en diferentes archivo objetos:

> Observación mía: Esto solo pasa cuando se usan archivos obj, si lo incluye directamente en main no tendrías este problema, o simplemente usa la declaración inline

#### global.h

```c
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include <allegro.h>
#include <string>

//const int FRAME_RATE = 30; //Antigua declaración.
inline const int FRAME_RATE = 30;//Declarado inline

//unsigned int counter;
inline unsigned int counter; //En Allegro, para que cumpla su función, es obligatorio que esta variable sea global y volatile

void aumentar_counter();

//BITMAP *buffer;//Declaración anterior.
inline BITMAP *buffer;//Declaración actual.

#endif
```

Lo que cambié fue:

```
//BITMAP *buffer;//Declaración anterior.
inline BITMAP *buffer;//Declaración actual.
inline unsigned int counter;
...

//const int FRAME_RATE = 30; //Antigua declaración.
inline const int FRAME_RATE = 30;//Declarado inline
```

Comment: Cosa curiosa, les pongo el inline como tú lo hiciste, y aún siguen mostrando exactamente el mismo error. Todavía más, muevo las globales a la función main, antes de #incluir framework.h, y muestran el error dos veces con cada variable. Estoy seguro que debe haber una forma de hacer un programa con múltiples archivos y variables globales donde el linker no se queje tanto. Además, qué curioso que con FRAME_RATE nadie proteste

Comment: Descuido mio, no agregue la variable counter, @Satoshi y tampoco le veo sentido de incluir framework,h en framework.cpp, pues no hay variables globales y ahí se declaran las funciones, deberías incluirlo si piensas usar clases en framework.cpp